# Understanding pseudo code

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pseudocode

I was reading some sorting algorithm here (http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/insertion-sort) and i saw following line

```
i = 2:n
```

Can someone explains what does this mean ?

Theoretically I understand that for insertion sort i = size of array. But can someone tell me if i am getting it right ?

Comment: n = a random integer, `i = 2:n` would mean `i` is either an integer `>= 2`, but in this contexts more likely: a range / array from 2 to some higher number `n`.

Comment: My best guess would be that it's to denote the range from 2 to `n`, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This notation is often used to describe ranges of numbers. In your case `for i = 2:n` can be read as "for every i in numbers 2 to n". If n=4, the loop will run three times with i = 2, i = 3, and i = 4.

Answer (score 3):

In the pseudocode on the site you linked:

```
for i = 2:n,
    for (k = i; k > 1 and a[k] < a[k-1]; k--) 
        swap a[k,k-1]

end
```

The first line means that the second and third lines are repeated `n-1` times, and the first time, `i = 2`, the second time, `i = 3`, the third time, `i = 4`, and the last time `i = n`.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a loop, similar to

```
for(int i = 2 ; i <= n ; i++)
```

Wherea `n` is defined somewhere above the loop.

Basically: Let `i` be 2, increment it until it reaches `n` and use `i` for each iteration to do some behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It means iteration with `i` taking values from `2` to `n`.